# Why does AT86RF231 not send my data?

Tags: python, raspberry-pi, raspberry-pi2

I've been searching the web for days now and neither the web nor the manual helped me.

In fact I want a simple send and receive routine in Python for the `AT86RF231`. Both radios are plugged on a raspberry pi.
I think all the registers are set up properly but when trying to send a packet, there is nothing received on the receiver side and the `IRQ TRX_END` is not raised as well.
The implemented "`test mode`" does not work for me as well and I can't figure out why.

The datasheet is available [here](http://www.atmel.com/images/doc8111.pdf).

```
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-

import spidev
import time
import RPi.GPIO as GPIO
import binascii
import string
import random


#Definitions        
dont_care = 0
nRST = 27
#Abkürzung
spi=spidev.SpiDev()

#make sure /RST is high
GPIO.setwarnings(False)
GPIO.setmode(GPIO.BCM)
#GPIO 27 als Output konfigurieren
GPIO.setup(nRST, GPIO.OUT)
GPIO.output(nRST,GPIO.HIGH)


#Reset
def reset():
    GPIO.output(nRST,GPIO.LOW)
    time.sleep(0.001)
    GPIO.output(nRST,GPIO.HIGH)
    while (read(0x01,0)[1]!= 0 | read(0x01,0)[1]!= 8):
        time.sleep(0.001)
    print "Reset complete"

# get Device ID 
def DevID():
    ID = spi.xfer2([0x9C,0])
    print "ID:"
    print ID

#write data
def write(addr, value):
    spi.xfer2([addr | 0xC0, value])

#read data
def read(addr, value):
    data = spi.xfer2([addr | 0x80, value])
    return data

#read framebuffer
def frameread():
    output = spi.xfer2([0x20,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0])
    return output

#read transmissionstatus 
def transstatus():
    status = read(0x01,0)[1]
    print status
    if (status == 0):
        print "P_ON"
    elif (status == 1):
        print "Busy_RX"
    elif (status== 2):
        print "Busy_TX"
    elif (status == 6):
        print "RX_ON"
    elif (status==8):
        print "TRX_Off"
    else :
        print "Kontrolle des Status nötwendig"
#?
def status():
    status = spi.xfer2([0x81, 0])
    if (status[1]==0):
        print "Status: default"
    elif (status[1]==1):
        print "Status: monitor TRX_Status"
    elif (status[1]==2):
        print "Status: monitor PHY_RSSI"
    elif (status[1]==3):
        print "Status: monitor IRQ_Statis"
    return status[1]

#Continuous Transmission Test Mode
#Register werden in der Anleitung beschrieben
def testmode():
    reset()
    DevID()
    write(0x0E, 0x01)
    write(0x04, 0x00)
    write(0x02, 0x03)
    write(0x03, 0x01)
    write(0x08, 0x33)
    write(0x05, 0x00)
    status()
    while(read(0x01, 0x00) == 8):
        time.sleep(0.1)
        print "Transmission in progress - waiting"
    write(0x036, 0x0F)
    # hier muss der Inhalt beschrieben werden
    #0x60 Frame write Acess,10 Frames, Inhalt
    spi.xfer2([0x60,0x0A,1,2,6,4,5,6,7,8,9,10])
    write(0x1C, 0x54)
    write(0x1C, 0x46)
    write(0x02, 0x09)
    print read(0x0F, 0x01)
    while(read(0x0F, 0x01)[1]!=0):
        time.sleep(0.1)
        print "Waiting for PLL_Lock"
    write(0x02, 0x02)
    #Messung
    transstatus()
    print "Messung durchführen"
    time.sleep(10)
    write(0x1C, 0x00)
    #Reset machen
    reset()

#enable receiver
def receiver_enable():
    write(0x02,0x08)    
    write(0x02,0x06)

# make randomisierte Pakete 
def id_generator(size,chars=string.digits):
    return ''.join(random.choice(chars) for _ in range(size))

#generate Frame
def make_frame(length, power, transmission_type):
    data = id_generator(length)
    dataframe = []
    dataframe.append(length + 2)
    dataframe.append(power)
    dataframe.append(transmission_type)
    for i in range(0,len(data),1):
         dataframe.append(data[i])
    return dataframe

# send frame
def send_frame(frame):
    write(0x0E, 0x01)
    write(0x04, 0x00)
    write(0x02, 0x03)
    write(0x08, 0x33)
    write(0x05, 0x00)
    write_frame(frame)
    while (read(0x01,0)[1] != 8):
        time.sleep(0.1)
        print "Waiting for TRX_OFF"
    write(0x02, 0x09)
    time.sleep(.1)
    while(read(0x01,0)[1] != 9):
        time.sleep(0.1)
        print "Waiting for PLL_Lock"
    #TX start
    write(0x02, 0x02)
    while(read(0x01, 0)[1] == 2):
        time.sleep(0.1)
        print "Busy TX"

#set transmit power 1-16
def set_power(power):
    write(0x05, power)

# Framebuffer write
def write_frame(data):
    if isinstance(data, basestring):
        spi.xfer2([0x60,len(data)] + [int(ord(i)) for i in list(data)])
    else:
        print "bin heir"
        dataframe = []
        dataframe.append(0x60)
        dataframe.append(len(data))
        for i in range(0,len(data),1):
            dataframe.append(int(data[i]))
        print dataframe
        spi.xfer2(dataframe)
```

sender routine

```
spi.open(0,0)
reset()
while(1):
    testmode()
    time.sleep(1)

spi.close()
```

receiver routine

```
spi.open(0,0)
reset()
receiver_enable()
while(1):
    print frameread()

spi.close()
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found a solution by myself. The selected Channel was actually wrong. 0x33 was in the manual given but this Channel does not exist. Change this in transmitter and receiver register and everything will work like charm.